# chrome extension tab event listeners are not working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

i want my extension to capture any url that is created and alert it am totally new to chrome extensions it is my first extension ^_^
 here is the manifest.json file:

```
{
    "name":"modz",
    "manifest_version":2,
    "version":"1.0",
    "description":"this ext. will help you record all the urls you have visited",
    "browser_action":
    {
    "default_icon":"icon.png",
    "default_popup":"popup.html"
    },
    "permissions":[
          "tabs"
        ]

}
```

and this is the html and it is containing the scrpit:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener(function ( tab ){
alert(tab.url);


});
    chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
   alert(changeInfo.url);

}); 

chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(function(activeInfo) {
  chrome.tabs.get(activeInfo.tabId, function(tab){
     console.log(tab.url);

  });
});
</script>
    <style type="text/css">
     body{
       width:440px;
     }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="hello">hi this is the pop up </div>
</body>
</html>
```

thanks in  advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting that script code in background.js instead, and add this to your manifest:

```
"background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
}
```

popup.html only runs when the user clicks the browser action icon. background.js will be running throughout the session.
Check out this extension guide if you haven't already: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview

Comment: should i then include the js file in the html file or just declare it in the manifest ?

Comment: Just declare it in the manifest, and the extension will run it automatically. You don't need popup.html or the browser action at all for this.